# Android - Java - Predefined XML templates to use in code

Tags: java, android, xml, loops, templates

I came from HTML/JavaScript world to Android development and there is one thing I cannot still figure out.

Is there any templating system available for Android development in Java?

I mean, when I create layout in HTML/Javascript, I use Mustache.js to define the template once and I use it in the app to dynamically create the final layout in the application.

In Java, when I want to create for example Buttons in loop, I do somethink like this:

```
for (Int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ {
    Button button = new Button(mContext);
    button.set_some_parameter_here()
    button.set_some_other_parameter_here()
    etc()...

    layout.addView(button);
}
```

Is there any way how I predefine the View (or entire layout) in XML (with variables to be replaced in Java loop like {text} of the Button) and afterwards I only insert this template in loop to the final layout viewgroup?

I know how to define static layout in XML, I am asking if there is any way to define XML for future dynamic print.

Thank you.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a list of buttons dynamically you can use a recyclerview of buttons and handle each button as you want.

Check this [RecyclerView Button Android Studio Example Get Click Position](https://medium.com/@parsaniahardik/recyclerview-button-android-studio-example-get-click-position-574b7b181895)

And if you want to reuse an xml template you can use include keyword, 
here is the reference [Re-using layouts with](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)

Another way to use predefined layouts/views, you can create your custom view (button) and set it's attributes then use it.Check the example below -You can extend Button and set it's attributes.

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {
  // Set your parameters    

}
```

Comment: You can also inflate a layout inside another existing layout in your Java code.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Actually, the Button example was really only for example, my goal was to predefine "more complex" View in XML and be able to use in code (dynamically bind data to it so I could dynamically create "how many views I want" from this predefined XML template). I found that the Adapters could be the answers - according to this YT tutorial at least: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1olQnH9bE2c :-) Thanks